# Implementing Min priority Queue(C++ STL) using user-defined objects

Tags: c++11, stl, priority-queue

I am implementing Prims Algorithm. I have a vector of Edges along with their weights. 
The problem is, after inserting, the queue does not remain in increasing order according to weight of edges.

The relevant code is given below:-

```
struct weightcomp // To be used solely for priority Queue...
{
    bool operator()(Edge &E1, Edge &E2)
    {
        if(E1.weight > E2.weight)
            return true;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<Edge,std::vector<Edge>,weightcomp> PQ; // Priority Queue for Edges

void visit(std::vector<Edge> &PMST, int i) // PMST = Vector of edges and i = name of node
{
    for(auto iter = PMST.begin();iter != PMST.end();++iter)
    {
        if((*iter).u == i || (*iter).v == i)
        {
            PQ.push((*iter));
            (*iter).del = true;  // Mark the vectors elements to be removed.
        }
    }

    PMST.erase(std::remove_if(PMST.begin(),PMST.end(),[](Edge e){ return e.del;}),PMST.end()); // Delete the marked elements
}
```

What am I missing in the implementation?

Comment: You don't have an `else` branch in `weightcomp::operator()`, which results in UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour because your comparison doesn't always return a value. You need something along the lines of

```
bool operator()(const Edge &E1, const Edge &E2) const
{
    return E1.weight > E2.weight;
}
```

Where I have made the parameters `const` references because a comparison shouldn't modify them, and the operator `const` because it doesn't change the state of the functor.